# Invalid use of group function after making a select from a function

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a function for mysql:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE FUNCTION suma(price CHAR(50))
RETURNS CHAR(200)
BEGIN
DECLARE suma CHAR(200);
SET suma=SUM(price);
RETURN suma;
END ;;
```

When i'm trying to make the select in SQL, it returns me '#1111 - Invalid use of group function' error.
The select looks like this:

```
SELECT suma(price) FROM books;
```

The 'SELECT SUM(price) FROM books;' is working. Why the function suma(price) isn't working?
Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You cannot have `sum()` except in a query with a `select`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not define an aggregate function this way using a user defined function in sql.

As per the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/udf-aggr-calling.html

So in other-words you can not do it using sql stored function, they need to be in c or c++